# Setup Groovy in Mac OS X

Tags: snow-leopard

I have downloaded groovy-binary-1.7.10.zip, unzipped @ `/Users/sarbbottam/SW Developments/groovy-1.7.10` and navigated to `/Users/sarbbottam/SW Developments/groovy-1.7.10/bin`. I tried to execute `./groovysh`; however, I got the below error.

```
Sarbbottam-Bandyopadhyays-MacBook-Pro:bin sarbbottam$ ./groovysh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Developments/groovy-1/7/10/bin/groovy/icns
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Developments.groovy-1.7.10.bin.groovy.icns
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Sarbbottam-Bandyopadhyays-MacBook-Pro:bin sarbbottam$
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Try renaming your SW Developments folder to one word (with no spaces or an underscore).

Looks like the space is causing a problem in loading the library.

Comment: I do not think that space cause a problem. SW Developments is written as either SW\ Developments or "SW Developments".

Answer (score 1):

You need to install groovy in a path without spaces in it - this would be the easiest solution.

Otherwise you need to edit almost all of the groovy scripts in the bin folder - each time you upgrade too.

Comment: I have figured it out.
http://tshawkins.blogspot.com/2008/03/groovy-on-leopard.html

Answer (score 0):

It can also be achieved by using the following:

Unpack the archive and move it to /usr/share

```
$cd /usr/share
$sudo chown -R root:wheel groovy-1.7.10/
$sudo chmod 0755 groovy-1.7.10/bin/*
$sudo ln -s groovy-1.7.10 groovy
$cd /usr/local/bin
$ln -s /usr/share/groovy/bin/groovy groovy
$ln -s /usr/share/groovy/bin/groovyc groovyc
```

There is no need to alter the `$PATH`. `/usr/local/bin` is already in `$PATH`. So just make a symbolic link of `/usr/share/groovy/bin/groovy` and `/usr/share/groovy/bin/groovyc` in `/usr/local/bin`.

Regards,